# Adding a number for each variable with the same name

Tags: jquery, variables, append, netsuite

This is going to sound very confusing and complex, im sure of it.

Since NetSuite is very limited, I'm improvising to use my **Item List Cell internalid** to reference to **my related item cell**

I can't seem to append the `.inlineitem` to the closest `.niirelateditems`div without appending the same item to all `.niirelateditems`

On the **Item List Cell** I have this code:

```
<script>var itemcellid = "<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>"</script>
```

in my **related item cell**, I have this code:

```
$(".inlineitem<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>").appentTo(".niirelateditems"+itemcellid+"");
```

When viewing the code live, `<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>` outputs the internal ID of the cell that it's referencing. So the output of the script would be:

```
$(".inlineitem12345678").appentTo(".niirelateditems"+itemcellid+"");
```

Is it possible for me to add a unique number to each **itemcellid** that gets called? and then on the **related item cell** I can tell my script to reference it's parallel **itemcellid**? Basically **itemcellid** would be **itemcellid1** in the first cell, and the second cell would be **itemcellid2** and the **related item cell** would search for it's correlating **itemcellid**

In NetSuite, these Item cells run on a "foreach" function, so if I leave **itemcellid** the way it is, the script in the **related item cell** will append all items to the last item of the list.

I hope this wasn't confusing, I can't explain any better unfortunately.

Comment: Need more info. What record type are you editing? Is this for Suitescript or SCA? The code you posted seems to have typos: "appentTo" instead of "appendTo", have you tried this code?